# what is the difference between run and lead a campaign?

Tags: word-difference

There are a few words which collocate with the word "campaign". Could you please explain the difference between them? Is it possible to change "lead" to "run" in this context: "The politicians who led the Leave campaign did not seem to expect to win".

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> The politicians who **led** the Leave campaign did not seem to expect to win.
>   The politicians who **ran** the Leave campaign did not seem to expect to win.

both have equivalent meaning, however

> Many politicians **ran** the Leave campaign, but Nigel Farage **led** the Leave campaign

Many politicians **led** different aspects of the campaign while collectively **running** it.